# Passing object ByRef into sub rather than using a function - Is this bad programming practice... why?

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop

I created the following recursive routine to get all the checked nodes in a treeview:

```
    Sub GetAllCheckedNodes(ByVal tn As TreeNode, ByRef NodesList As List(Of TreeNode))
        If tn.Checked Then NodesList.Add(tn)

        For Each nd As TreeNode In tn.Nodes
            GetAllCheckedNodes(nd, NodesList)
        Next
    End Sub
```

Basically, the way I use it would be to declare an empty `List(Of Treenode)` and then pass it into this routine as the second argument.
My question is that I've been told this is "not great" programming practice - Why and what could go wrong?

It seems to be the most elegant solution I could come up with to get this to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to pass the list `ByRef` -- it's already a reference type. Just pass it by value and you'll still be able to add checked items to it.

Comment: LO AND BEHOLD!!! - Works just as fine without the `ByRef`... I'm thinking I have an incorrect idea of what `Byref` means, then. I always assumed it meant that you were dealing with the original variable whereas `ByVal` gave you a copy of the variable instead... If you were willing to, could you point me in the right direction to understand the differences / explain the use of `ByRef`, please??

Comment: When you pass a reference type `ByRef`, you're passing a reference to the reference. It would allow you to change the variable to refer to a *different* list. I'll dig up a link...

Comment: @JohnBustos That's exactly what it means.  In this case, the variable is not the list itself, because `List` is a reference type.  The variable holds nothing but a reference to where the actual list is...elsewhere.  It doesn't matter whether you copy that reference *by value* or by reference since you're not changing what the reference, you're just mutating the object that the reference points to.

Comment: This explains in more detail: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/135354-reference-types-value-types-byval-byref/

Answer (score 2):

The more common solution here would be, rather than mutating a collection that's passed in, to return a collection/sequence that represents all of the nodes that meet the condition.  Personally I think `IEnumerable` fits this situation well, as you can either use an iterator block or just concat the results together to so that the method optionally adds itself and then returns everything from the recursive call.

This has several benefits.  First, it's easier to call; there's no need to create a list, pass it in, ensure there's no threading/concurrent modification issues, and then use it later, you can just call the method and use the result.

Comment: Thanks as always, @Servy - Makes good sense... I thought I was being smart and saving on space by not having to declare a variable within the routine this way, but if that's better programming practice, so be it! - Thanks!!!

Comment: ... I apologize @Servy, If I could choose 2 answers, I would definitely vote both you and Jon because you both helped fully explain my question and further my knowledge - I'm so grateful to you for that and simply choosing Jon's because he answered first. thank you so much, Servy!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that of expectations from other programmers and the fact that you are relying on side-effects (that is, changes to a passed in parameter).

When someone sees a `Get*`, the expectation is that it will *return* a value.

You can still have a recursive *function* and not have to rely on changing a passed in parameter.